# Is there a web service from ArcGIS that allows updating versioned SDE with ArcPad AXF data?

Tags: arcgis-9.3, web-service, arcpad

Here is my situation, currently we have a number of employees updating a copy of a checked out axf database using ArcPad on mobile devices.  Our current process is very time consuming since it involves uploading the axf file, checking in the axf to a version SDE geodatabase and then check out the axf again to get the most updated version of the axf with their edits, plus the checked in edits of other users.  Also, this is in a disconnect environment.  The users are usually in a remote location with limit internet access.  My question is this, does ArcGIS have a web service that will allow a user to “check in” their changes and then “check out” all the edits to update their personal copy of the axf with the most recent data?  I am looking for a solution to allow bi-directional updates to the data in almost real-time?  If anyone has done this or something like it, I would really like to hear your ideas on how to solve this issue or the reasons why this will not work?  Or if someone has a totally different approach I would like to your ideas as well.

Thanks.

Tim

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to publish your ArcPad project to ArcGIS Server using the server extension in ArcPad. Add the published layers to ArcPad using "Add Data From Server", edit and then "Synchronise Data With ArcGIS Server" (requires an internet connection) - both options are present in ArcPad under the "Add Layer" menu. It's a bit tricky to get into details - it is all documented in the ArcPad Help - but this will allow multiple users to sync their .axf files back and forth to the SDE database in real time.

Hannah

Comment: Thanks for the reply Hannah.  But unforunately, the version of ArcGIS does not allow us to use the "Add Data From Server" option in ArcPad (according to ESRI).  Do you have any other solution(s) that might work?  I am kind of hitting a wall here, trying to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely possible with a bit of custom development.  What you want to do on ArcGIS server is create a mapping/data service to your geodatabase.  Then via JScript in ArcPad, access the AGS JavaScript API, retrieving any new records and uploading changed records.  It's a bit of work to set up, but once done, runs smoothly, and operates very well on limited bandwidth links.

Answer (score 0):

i have tried to run a demo using arcgis server entreprise 10 and arcpad 10 extension for Arcgis server but , the server gave me an error the service couldn't start , could it gimme the error because i haven't Arcgis server entreprise Advanced edition ??